# Is it possible to use Bings street view with ASP.NET or Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, google-maps, silverlight-3.0, bing-maps, google-street-view

I wont write web application, which will use street view of Bing(or Googles one if it can be used by ASP.NET or Silverlight).
I found SDK for Bing map: http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/silverlight/

But I need streets 3D view.
Is it possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible -  see Bing Maps Extended Modes.

Also check out these articles:

- http://www.bing.com/toolbox/blogs/maps/archive/2009/12/10/adding-streetside-and-enhanced-birds-eye-to-your-applications.aspx
- http://innovativesingapore.com/2010/06/bing-maps-streetside-api/

**Please Note**
The Microsoft Connect page for the Bing Maps SDK is the authoritative site for the SDK. The links to Connect **within in the 2 above URLs are to a deprecated site**.  Use https://connect.microsoft.com/bingmapapps instead.

Comment: But there is a little problem. I can't downlod  Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.ExtendedModes dll. I can't fing it. I tried to download it from 2-nd link, but nothing available. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @Ryan Bates. That was what I need. But I can't add Streed side view. Can you give a link to some tutorial or some code about how to da that? Thanks