# How to use Streetside of Bing map with silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, bing-maps, google-street-view

I am tring to use Bings Streetside.
I have searched a lot in Google but nothing.
In all post says, that I need to download Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.ExtendedModes.dll but all links are invalid. I can't download it.
[These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099687/is-it-possible-to-use-bings-street-view-with-asp-net-or-silverlight) inks are incorrect too.
What can I do?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use Bings street view with ASP.NET or Silverlight?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099687/is-it-possible-to-use-bings-street-view-with-asp-net-or-silverlight)

Comment: Hi @p.campbell, it is not duplicate. That question also had been asked by ME, so it can't be duplicate, and if you have read the question you can see, that link I have given is the same as yours.

Comment: You should have updated the original question rather than re-asking it.

Comment: Nothing available under link you gived as answer(which was later deleted). There is only (none available) message under Links tag. I have already registered there.
Thaks for link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bing Maps SDK is likely what you need. It's unfortunate that the old/deprecated Connect site doesn't redirect visitors to the new site within Connect.

The `BingMapAppSDK.msi` is available from https://connect.microsoft.com/bingmapapps

The version available today is quite recent:

- Title     Bing Map App SDK
- Release Date  6/7/2010
- Size  3.87 MB
- Version  1.0.1006.0415

Comment: Hi @p.campbell.
That was what I need. But I can't add Streed side view.
Can you give a link to some tutorial or some code about how to da that?
Thanks